# I saw a nightmare, dreamed a nightmare or something else?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Which one is the correct one?
And if there is more than one answer, when to use each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, we just say "I *had* a nightmare".

> I didn't get much sleep last night. I had a nightmare and woke up around 3 am and I was so upset by it that I wasn't able to get back to sleep.

The word "nightmare" already implies that it was a dream, so "dreamt/dreamed" is redundant.

Comment: To add on, dreams are also spoken about in this way. It's much more common to say "I had a dream about you" rather than "I dreamed about you".